# Selling Sql Server 2008 to upper management? How?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know the advantages of upgrading from sql server 2005 to sql server 2008, but upper management could care less about t-sql debugging, intellisense, the merge statment, etc..., so what are some features in sql server 2008 that upper management might actually find worth while.

Comment: Check Microsoft's SQL site and I'm sure you'll find plenty of material on why you should use their product.  Why come here for this?

Comment: I am not upper management.  This is a valid question and as I stated in the question, management does not care about most of the features Microsoft lists on their site, so I want to get others opinions on what features management might like that maybe I am overlooking.

Comment: Tell them "the World's gonna end unless we buy SQL Server 2008, now."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could try showing them some of Microsoft's case studies that have some relevance to your company.  It might give them some warm fuzzies to see that someone else has done something similar.

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/case-studies.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will check it out.

Comment: Been reading the link you sent me.  Great link by the way.  Had to add that because it is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if the level of management that is deciding which database technology to buy doesn't understand t-sql debugging and intellisense then your company has the wrong people making technical decisions.

Comment: This scenario is all too common at most companies.  It is the responsibility of the programming manager to know enough "suit-speak" to be able to make the benefits case to upper management in their own language.

Comment: At my company "upper management" would not care what database software we were using.  They would only care how the system would help the users.  This would be like if you tried to visit and website and your computer had to OK the route it would take to get to the webserver.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying tster.  Unfortunately, when it comes to any amount of money, this always happpens.

Answer (score 1):

Transparent database encryption - even if the backup files get stolen (or the entire data files) the database cannot be read. Reduces the cost of data loss and embarrassing media attention.

SQL Audit - see who's doing what with the data with no 3rd party tools necessary

Policy-based management - reduce the amount of time needed to ensure the servers adhere to a defined policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitly get the product released faster.

Comment: What if they ask how can we get the product released faster?